# jquery or native can't get element by its ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, in a page there is a div with id `#SCPcustomOptionsDiv`. I want to move that div to a right place where it should be.

I tried using jQuery as well as native javascript, but can't get this to work. When i try to run the script using debugger, the result is null. here is the script.

```
jQuery('#SCPCustomOptionsDiv') // return []
document.getElementById('SCPCustomOptionsDiv') // return null
```

and here is some snippet of the source

```
<span style="display:none;" class="scp-please-wait"><img src="http://optimallyorganic.webmate.co/skin/frontend/base/default/images/scp-ajax-loader.1413318518.gif" class="v-middle" alt="" /> &nbsp; Loading... &nbsp;</span>
        <div id="SCPcustomOptionsDiv"></div>
</fieldset>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $$('#product-options-wrapper dl').each(function(label) {
        label.addClassName('last');
    });
</script>
```

is camelcase id matter when selecting the div using javascript?

Comment: yes, camelcase for all selectors definately matters

Comment: Why you are using `$$('...`?

Comment: @Tushar: that is a script generated by magento, not mine.

Comment: `SCPCustomOptionsDiv` != `SCPcustomOptionsDiv `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C in SCP**c**ustomOptionsDiv is lowercase in your HTML and uppercase in your script. IDs are case-sensitive.

```
SCPcustomOptionsDiv
   ^
```

vs.

```
SCPCustomOptionsDiv
   ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `SCPcustomOptionsDiv` in your script not `SCPCustomOptionsDiv`

```
jQuery('#SCPcustomOptionsDiv')
document.getElementById('SCPcustomOptionsDiv')
```